# Azure B2C authentication redirects locally, but not when hosted on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I'm new to Azure AD B2C. I'm trying to set up azure B2C authentication for an MVC application.
The login works fine locally, but when it's not working on server.
The application is hosted on Azure AD.
I don't know if I missed something!! Can someone please help?

```
private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
        {
            return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {               
                // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
                MetadataAddress = metaDataAddress,
                AuthenticationType = policy,
                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
                ClientId = clientId,             
                //ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
                },
                Scope = "openid",
                ResponseType = "id_token",

                //  used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                    RoleClaimType = "role",
                    SaveSigninToken = true 
                }
            };
        }
```

When it is deployed on to the server, after sign in, it is not returning to the application. Instead the page seems to blink and in between I can see something displayed as "As part of the authentication process the page is displayed several times, please click the button to continue"..

Comment: Things need to take care: 1. Redirect URI must match with your Azure hosted website. 2. Try checking in Private browser or another browser which don't have a session of Portal.azure.com

Comment: @Ramakrishna yes, the  redirectUri matches with the website and also this is added in B2C application ReplyUrl

Answer (score 0):

Startup.cs file seems alright to me.Couple things to cross check:

- redirectUri matches with the website
- Here is my signup and sign in action method:

```js
public void SignIn()
            {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
               
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" }, Startup.SignInPolicyId);
            }
        }
    
            public void SignUp()
            {
                if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                        new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" }, Startup.SignUpPolicyId);
                }
            }
```

I have followed below github repo and it worked for me. Try this and see if it works

https://github.com/tjoudeh/Azure-Active-Directory-B2C/tree/master/AADB2C.WebClientMvc/Controllers

Reference:

http://bitoftech.net/2016/08/31/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-mvc-web-app/

Please provide the detailed error with entire code base will try to reproduce at my end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) In fact the problem was due to missing https instead of http at the url beginning. It works now :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped. Please accept as an answer as it will help others who have the same ask.